# SSRS Cache Schedule Re

Tags: powershell, caching, reporting-services

I have about ~50 reports that are scheduled to be "cached" on a recurring schedule (image below).

[image: SSRS Caching Options Image]

Is this information only available in Report Server Database or can the schedule information be retrieved using Powershell? All of the "obvious" methods I've run thus far (with powershell ise) either return no information or boolean values (all 'false')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetItemHistoryOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemhistoryoptions.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the schedule for the report item.

Then based on the type of `Item` property of the `ScheduleDefinitionOrReference` `[ref]` parameter of the method, you can decide how to show the information.

Type of the `Item`, can be one of `MinuteRecurrence`, `DailyRecurrence`, `WeeklyRecurrence`, `MonthlyRecurrence` or `MonthlyDOWRecurrence`.

**Example**

For example to format `MonthlyRecurrence` you can use such code:

```
$svcUrl = 'http://the-host-name/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx'
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $svcUrl -UseDefaultCredential
$reports = $svc.ListChildren("/", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }

$KeepExecutionSnapshots = $false
$ScheduleDefinitionOrReference = New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinitionOrReference

foreach ($report in $reports) {
    $result = $svc.GetItemHistoryOptions($report.Path, 
        [ref]$KeepExecutionSnapshots, 
        [ref]$ScheduleDefinitionOrReference)
    if($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item -is [RS.MonthlyRecurrence])
    {
        "'$($report.Name)' Schedule Information:"
        "StartDateTime: $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.StartDateTime)"
        "StartDateTime: $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.EndDate)"
        "EndDateSpecified: $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.EndDateSpecified)"
        "Days: $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item.Days)"
        $months = Get-Member `
            -InputObject $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item.MonthsOfYear) `
            -MemberType Property | Where-Object {
            $ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item.MonthsOfYear.$($_.Name) -eq $true
        }
        "Months:$($months.Name -join ",")" 
    }
}
```

And the result will be something like this:

```
'MyReport' Schedule Information:
StartDateTime: 12/19/2017 18:00:00
StartDateTime: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
EndDateSpecified: False
Days: 1,3-5
Months:August,December,July,November,October,September
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I was looking for. Only difference, I had to use the GetExecutionOptions() method to get the data I was looking for, instead of the GetItemHistoryOptions(). Both work in the same manner, just different schedule objects. Thanks again!